# Are there any free php crawlers?

Tags: php, phpcrawl

In the past I have used my own crawler, but now I need something more robust and I was wondering if there were any good free php crawlers?

Answer (score 1):

http://php-crawler.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I was thinking about something more robust.. Something with documentation maybe?